# Comparing the values of two different objects

Tags: javascript

I have two objects.

```
"Initial": {"LF_Min": --,
          "LF_Max": --,
          "RF_Min": --,
          "RF_Max": --};

"Result":{"LF_Status":--,
          "RF_Status":--};
```

I have to check if the value of `Result.LF_Status` is in the range of `Initial.LF_Min` and `Initial.LF_Max` or not.

How can I check for this condition in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the properties in your objects are of type `Number`:

```
function validate(initial, result) {
  return
    result.LF_Status >= initial.LF_Min &&
    result.LF_Status <= initial.LF_Max;
}
```

When I'm extensively checking for range constraints, I find it useful to extend the `Number` prototype like so:

```
Number.prototype.isInRange = function(min, max) {
  return this >= min && this <= max;
}
```

With this extension defined, you can achieve your object validation in a more concise way:

```
if(Result.LF_Status.isInRange(Initial.LF_Min, Initial.LF_Max)) {
  // Your code here
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

see this : http://jsfiddle.net/dwboy657/

```
Initial={"LF_Min": "10", "LF_Max": "20", "RF_Min": "30", "RF_Max": "50"};
Result={"LF_Status":"21", "RF_Status":"4"};

function checkRange(compareObj,resultObj){
    if(resultObj.LF_Status>=compareObj.LF_Min && resultObj.LF_Status<=compareObj.LF_Max)
    {
       return true;
    }else{
         return false;
    }

}

alert('Result LF is within range: '+checkRange(Initial,Result));
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, there's no such thing as a "JSON object" - if you have the JSON representation of two objects, they are basically string literals that can be parsed into a Javascript object. Once you parse them into javascript objects (using `object = JSON.parse(string)`), you can manipulate them in standard ways, ie. use 2 comparisons to assert that the value of result is in the desired range.